# Linq:How to write Any in query syntax?

Tags: c#, linq

```
IEnumerable<Gruppe> cand = (IEnumerable<Gruppe>)populations.Where(
                            x => !x.Attributes.Any(
                                 y => y.GetType() == typeof(Arbeit)
                              )
                          );
```

I wondered how I could write the above in query syntax but stumbled because of the Any method.

Comment: use select(cand => IEnumerable<Gruppe>... )

Comment: you mean to replace the cast?

Comment: sorry! i thought you were asking about the above code in query syntax. You probably meant the `.Where(...)` part?

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent of `Any` in query syntax. So the best you can do is:

```
IEnumerable<Gruppe> cand =
   from population in populations
   where !population.Attributes.Any(y => y.GetType() == typeof(Arbeit))
   select population
```

(I'm assuming that the cast to `IEnumerable<Gruppe>` is not necessary. If that assumption is wrong, you will need to add it back.)

Answer (score 0):

The `Any` could be refactored out, but you are still going to need a `Count`.

```
var cand = from population in populations
           let attributeCount = population.Attributes.Count
           let validAttributeCount = (
               from attribute in population.Attributes
               where attribute.GetType() != typeof(Arbeit)
               select attribute
           ).Count()
           where attributeCount == validAttributeCount
           select population;
```

Answer (score 0):

I like Svik's answer.

Another way to put it is like this:

```cs
IEnumerable<Gruppe> cand = 
    from population in populations
    where ( from attribute in population.Attributes
        where attribute.GetType() == typeof(Arbeit)
        select true).Any() == false
    select population
```